# Load DataFrame as Text File into HDFS and S3

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, dataframe, hdfs

I am trying to load a `DataFrame` into `HDFS` and `S3` as text format file using below code. `DataFrame` name is **finalData**.

```
val targetPath = "/user/test/File"
val now = Calendar.getInstance().getTime()
val formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
val timeStampAfterFormatting = formatter.format(now)
val targetFile = s"""$targetPath/test_$timeStampAfterFormatting.txt"""
finalData.repartition(1).rdd.saveAsTextFile(targetFile)
```

Using above code I can load the Data successfully. But file name is not same as I provided and also not in text format. A directory has created with the name as I mentioned.

> Directory Name - /user/test/File/test_20170918055206.txt
>
> -bash-4.2$ hdfs dfs -ls /user/test/File/test_20170918055206.txt
>
> Found 2 items
>
> /user/test/File/test_20170918055206.txt/_SUCCESS
>
> **/user/test/File/test_20170918055206.txt/part-00000**

I want to create the file as I mentioned instead of creating the directory. Can anyone please assist me.

Comment: You have pre-defined methods to write dataframes to hive tables. Did you check those out?

Comment: @philantrovert Yes, OP can: 1) Follow advices from answers linked by me 2) Save to Hive

Comment: It looks from your example like this is an exact duplicate.  Are we failing to understand what you are doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, this is **working as design**.

You got a **repartition** operation just before you saved your rdd data, and this would trigger a shuffle operation among your whole data, and eventually got a new rdd which had **only one partition**.

So this only one partition was stored in your HDFS as your **saveAsTextFile** operation.

This method is designed such way to let arbitrary number of partitions to be writed in a uniform way.

For example, if your rdd has 100 partitions, no **coalesce or repartition** before write to HDFS. **Then you will get a directory include _SUCCESS flag and 100 files!**

if this method is not designed such way, how rdd with multiple partitions could be stored in a **concise, uniform and elegant** way, and maybe user need to direct the multiple file names? ...ah, so tedious maybe

I hope this explanation helps you.

---

If you then need and a complete whole file on your local file system, just try the hadoop client command:

**hadoop fs -getmerge [src] [des]**